# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for my Register.php and login.php file

Tags: php, android, api

i am following http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ for making a login app.. i am getting 403 forbidden error.. i checked in internet but i didn't get a proper solution for this.. please help.. thanks in advance... my code..

```
<?php


class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            // verifying user password
            $salt = $user['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $user;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Function.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // use is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

in my browser i am getting error ture and parameters are missing..

.../login.php

```
{
error: true,
error_msg: "Required parameters email or password is missing!"
}
```

and in android logcat i am getting this error..

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.168.0.103/android_login_api/login.php
E/Volley: [12022] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.168.0.103/android_login_api/login.php
E/RegisterActivity: Login Error: null
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8c41f20
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8c28388
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
E/Volley: [12024] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.168.0.103/android_login_api/register.php
E/Volley: [12024] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.168.0.103/android_login_api/register.php
E/RegisterActivity: Registration Error: null
```

but when i tried in Advanced Rest client which is a crome extension i got responce like this:

```
{
error: false
uid: "584cb7ff41e6b7.87290144"
user: {
name: "Tapan Patro"
email: "tapan@gmail.com"
created_at: "2016-12-11 07:50:47"
updated_at: null
}-
}
```

but in android app i am getting a blank Toast message. I think its a blank error message. Please help . I have just started php.. so..

Android my login class

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        String email = user.get("email");

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtEmail.setText(email);

        // Logout button click event
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logoutUser();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
     * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
     * */
    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

please check above android java classes is there any mistake .. please let me know.

Comment: "$_POST['name']" and "email", "password", etc.. are not set. So when you are calling login.php and register.php you are not using POST correctly. Can you do a var_dump($_POST); in the beginning of the php file and give us the result?

Comment: no sir i don't know php that much .. if you will help sure i can do..

Comment: First you should simplify your question. The code for DB_Functions and the register.php is not needed as you face the same issue with login.php. Secondly we need the code showing how the login.php is called. And finally add a line just after "<?php" and paste "var_dump($_POST);" It will display in the output the content of $_POST

Comment: after adding var_dump in brower its showing this:C:\wamp64\www\android_login_api\login.php:3:
array (size=0)
  empty
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters email or password is missing!"}

Comment: Ok so visibly the issue is in Android side. You are not sending the parameters correctly. Check that getParams() is called and parameters are added such as : params.put("email", email); ...

Comment: i have added my android login and register classes .. please check .. is there any mistakes .. i have added paras.put("email", email) as you have mentioned.

Comment: Please add an Override for `getHeaders()` where you specify the charset as utf-8 such as `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` You can find an example here: http://envyandroid.com/android-volley-empty-parameters/